# How many Frontend pieces for 10 microservices?

Tags: angularjs, architecture, microservices

I have a bunch of microservices (10 to be precise), each with it´s own database, own code repo, own deployment pipeline, and all the recommended stuff for microservices architecture.

However, I dont have a clue on how to build the front end pieces, which are about to be developed by front end programmers.

Should I have 10 of them, one for each backend microservice?
Or should I have just one?

Maybe I can group some microservices, related to ADMIN role for instance, and create a single frontend for it? And another for another ROLE? Since I have about 4 ROLES, I may have 4 frontend apps?

For the final user, app (ui) should look like a monolithic.

What can you tell??

Briefly speaking, the services are (ADMIN, CLIENT, DISTRIBUTOR and RESPONDENT as roles):

1) oauth server (ADMIN, DISTRIBUTOR)

2) users service (ADMIN)

3) products service (ADMIN)

4) survey service (CLIENT)

5) jobposition service (DISTRIBUTOR)

6) answer service (RESPONDENT)

7) Email template service (ADMIN)

8) Credit/transaction service (ADMIN)

9 and 10) Batch services, but UI for showing batch status and result (ADMIN)

Thanks

Comment: How many front end "apps" are *needed* and what frameworks/stack is used to make them modular (or not-so-modular)? This question requires knowledge of the end design state/goal which takes into account the relationship between the exposed user interaction, the configuration and deployment, separations of major components to frameworks, etc. There is no inherent relationship with how *applications* map to the "microservices" or any other backend provider.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary that you need to have 10 front end services one for each backend service but try to have as many front end service as possible to fully utilize the advantages of microservices.

I don't think separating the front end based on the role is a good idea. Separation should be done based on the domain, products & sub products.

I am not completely aware of what those 10 services are so it is very difficult to say how to separate the front end service.